# Custom task on TFS for SoapUI

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm using SoapUI with TFS and have made a custom task in PowerShell (and TFS variables) to do so.

I've written the following code:

---

```
cd "C:\Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-2.1.0\bin\"
.\testrunner.bat -a -j -f"$env:Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory" "-RTestSuite Report" -EDEV\APIMGT_DEV "$env:Build.BinariesDirectory\_soapui\project.xml"
```

---

`$env:Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory"` is the path where the Test Results report will be sent; `$env:Build.BinariesDirectory\_soapui\project.xml` is the path where the project used by SoapUI is.

My problem is that, yes the report is searched at the right place (`Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory => D:\test\t01\_work\5\a\**\report.xml'`), but the project is searched at the wrong place (`C:\Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-2.1.0\bin\.BinariesDirectory\_soapui\project.xml`), combining the variable and the path to the binaries of the software ReadyAPI.

The errors are:

---

> [SoapUI] File [C:\Program
>   Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-2.1.0\bin.BinariesDirectory_soapui\project.xml]
>   does not exist, trying URL instead
>
> No test result files were found using search pattern
>   'D:\test\t01_work\5\a**\report.xml'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$env:Build_BinariesDirectory` and `$env:Build_ArtifactStagingDirectory` instead.

Comment: In fact, I found the error, I didn't put the environment variables in capitals and with a underscore instead of a dot, like $env:BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY. :)

Thank you, starain-MSFT. :)